# Content type with date groups

Tags: datetime

I currently have a content type called Training from which I have created a node for each training course I have. Each node has a multiple date field for when a course runs over more than one day (not necessarily days running after each other).

How would I create additional occurrences of a course dates without duplicating the node.

Eg

Fire course
2 day course
**Session 1:**
25/12/14 & 25/01/15
**Session 2:**
14/3/15 & 15/3/15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate your sessions from your course type. The ideal solution would be to implement [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection).

> Provides a field-collection field, to which any number of fields can
>   be attached.
>
> A field collection is internally represented as an entity, which is
>   embedded in the host entity. Thus, if desired field collections may be
>   viewed and edited separately too.

It is an actively maintained module with views integration. For a quick intro look at this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1V1ofpgUw-Y).